# java.sql.sqlexception column index out of range 0 <1 Using MySQL Databse

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, sqlexception

//Using MySql Database. creating a search query for mobile phone from IMEI No. //in swing based desktop application

```
int coulmn_count=rsmd.getColumnCount();
DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();
Vector column_name=new Vector();
Vector data_rows=new Vector();
for (int i = 1; i <=coulmn_count; i++) {
    column_name.addElement(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
}
dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(column_name);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,+coulmn_count);
while(rs.next())
{
    for (int j = 0; j <coulmn_count; j++) {
        data_rows=new Vector();
        data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
    }
    dtm.addRow(data_rows);
}
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,+coulmn_count);
table.setModel(dtm);
```

Answer (score 2):

The ResultSet is 1 based, not 0 based:

It looks like you got the code correct for the heading names:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=coulmn_count; i++) {
    column_name.addElement(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
}
```

But then you use 0 based for the column data.

```
for (int j = 0; j <coulmn_count; j++) {
    data_rows=new Vector();
    data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
}
```

Fix the code to start the index from 1.

Comment: Thank you Camickr.
I did changed that to 1 and Now it says java.lang.NullPointerException.
Along with that I tried several combinations of for loop. The result is Same. please Help.

Comment: @PranilDukare, A NullPointerException is the most common Exception you will get in Java. I can't help you solve the problem based on a few lines of code. You need to learn how to read the stack trace. It will tell you the line causing the problem. So then you determine the variable that is null and then fix the problem.